# median proof given G(t)=F(t-delta)

Tags: probability, median, proof

[image]

How can I do part a? I get stuck after using the formula for difference of 2 independent variable

Comment: You need to show a proper attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to prove $\Pr(Y-X < \Delta) =0.5$ (I remove the indexes $i$ and $j$ which are useless).
Start with
$$
\Pr(Y-X < \Delta) = \Pr(Y < \Delta +X)
$$
By independence between $X$ and $Y$, 
$$
\Pr(Y < \Delta + X) = \int \Pr(Y < \Delta + x) \mathrm{d}F(x).
$$
One has 
$$
\Pr(Y < \Delta + x) = G(\Delta+x) = F(x),
$$ 
thus
$$
\Pr(Y < \Delta + X) = \int F(x)  \mathrm{d}F(x).
$$
Now, observe that 
$$
\int F(x)  \mathrm{d}F(x) = \mathbb{E}[F(X)].
$$
When $F$ is continuous, it is well known that $F(X)$ follows a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. The result follows.

Comment: @GillianCheung More easy: you can write $Y=X'+\Delta$ where $X'$ is independent of $X$ and has the same law; then $\Pr(Y-X < \Delta) = \Pr(X'-X < 0)$, and this equals $0.5$ by symmetry ($X-X'$ has the same law as $X'-X$).